# jQUery html() with dynamic HTML inside <div>

Tags: jquery, html

i wanted to know whether  or not,there is a way by which we can extract HTML contents of a `<div>` using jQuery,given that the HTML content is not present but is extracted from another file such as a PHP file,dynamically

`$("#layer").html()` just gives a null value,as originally the file has no HTML inside `<div id="layer">`

thanks!

Comment: File has not html initially then how are you expecting to get its html?

Comment: you would need to wait until the dynamic content is populated into the `<div>`.  If you can post a little more example code, it would be helpful.  Can you show us the code that loads the div's content at runtime?

Comment: Your question is not clear, you need to elaborate or post relevant code.

Comment: name=$("text").val();
$("#onehead").html(name);
var name_to=$("#onehead").html;

alert(name_to);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say, use the either the `success` or `complete` callback functions of the `$.ajax()` function, everything inside these callbacks will be executed as soon as the `$.ajax()` function has completely loaded successfully.

Here: [jQuery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) Look at the [Callback Functions](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#callback-functions) section.

Answer (score 0):

Once the HTML has been generated inside the `div`, you can access it with the `.innerHTML` property:

```
alert($('dynamicDiv').innerHTML);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use 'complete' parameter in $.ajax to access this data.

Comment: $.ajax({
  url: "ajax.html",
  success: function(html){
    $("#results").append(html);
  }
  complete: function(){
    console.log('completed, now you have access to your dynamic data');
  }
});